# Bing Translator DNS address could not be found.datamarket.accesscontrol.windows.net

Tags: bing-translator-api

We are using the bing translater api in one of our projects for performing translations. The end point we use to call the api is:
http://api.microsofttranslator.com/v2/Http.svc/Translate?text=

To be able to call the API one has to authorize using the https://datamarket.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/OAuth2-13.

Sometime in the last few days this datamarket.accesscontrol.windows.net url has become unavailable because the domain name resolution fails.
**Exception:** System.Net.WebException
**Message:** The remote name could not be resolved: 'datamarket.accesscontrol.windows.net'

Is anyone else affected by this and know what is going on?

Answer (score 2):

The datamarket domain, and the ability to sign up via the Azure datamarket has been replaced by a regular Azure service.
Visit https://portal.azure.com and sign up for the Microsoft Translator Text API to get an API key. More detailed instructions at http://aka.ms/translatorgettingstarted.